# Ionic Framework and AngularJS - How to read mobile contacts into application

Tags: android, css, angularjs, cordova

Below is the code I have tried. When I execute the code below it appears as when I click a button in my application and it is opening device phone book and displaying contacts. When I click on any contact it is picked by application but it **should not** open device address book but when clicked it should display the contacts of my device in my application. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, r-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="platform-android platform-cordova platform-webview">

  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <button class="button" ng-click="pickContact()">Contacts</button>
      <h1 class="title">All Contacts</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">

        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="contact in data.selectedContacts">
                    <img src="{{contact.photos[0].value}}" ng-if="contact.photos.length > 0">

                    <h2>{{contact.displayName}}</h2>
                    <p ng-if="contact.emails.length > 0">{{contact.emails[0].type}} : {{contact.emails[0].value}}</p>
                    <p ng-if="contact.phones.length > 0">{{contact.phones[0].type}} : {{contact.phones[0].value}}</p>
                </a>

      </div>
      <p class="padding"></p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })

.service("ContactsService", ['$q',
  function($q) {

    var formatContact = function(contact) {

      return {
        "displayName": contact.name.formatted || contact.name.givenName + " " + contact.name.familyName || "Unknown Person",
        "emails": contact.emails || [],
        "phones": contact.phoneNumbers || [],
        "photos": contact.photos || []
      };

    };

    var pickContact = function() {

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if (navigator && navigator.contacts) {

        navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact) {

          deferred.resolve(formatContact(contact));
        });

      } else {
        deferred.reject("Hurray!!!!......  No contacts in desktop browser");
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
      pickContact: pickContact
    };
  }
])

.controller("AppCtrl", ['$scope', 'ContactsService',
  function($scope, ContactsService) {

    $scope.data = {
      selectedContacts: []
    };

    $scope.pickContact = function() {
      ContactsService.pickContact().then(
        function(contact) {
          $scope.data.selectedContacts.push(contact);
          console.log("Selected contacts=");
          console.log($scope.data.selectedContacts);

        },
        function(failure) {
          console.log("Hurray!!!!......  Failed to pick a contact");
        }
      );

    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `$cordovaContacts` which is a part of the `ngCordova` (ngCordova needs to be installed). You can install in your app with the command `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts`. Then there is a simple function to getting all contacts in your contacts list.

```
$scope.getAllContacts = function() {
  $cordovaContacts.find({filter: '',multiple:true}).then(function(allContacts) {
    $scope.contacts = allContacts;
  });
};
```

**Note:** It seems to be so that the `find()` function in `$cordovaContacts` can not be empty. Include ie. a filter in there for it to work.

**EDIT:**

This is a demonstration of the general structure and functions which you need to make the ngCordova contacts plugin to work.

Here's all my code you'll need in a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/osjppoqu/

And then I just call the `getAllContacts` function using a button click in my app.html file like this:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="getAllContacts()" class="button button-block button-positive">Get contacts</button>
```

REMEMBER it only works on a real device, probably not even emulator (haven't tested though). Include the `ngCordova` in your module. If you're calling the contacts plugin without a click or something remember that it is required that it's only called **AFTER** the device is ready. In Ionic you can do this with the following:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  // Call the plugin here
});
```

Comment: i already added that cordova plugin and tried the below getAllContacts() but it is not displaying contacts

Comment: Have you tried logging the `$scope.contacts` or the returned data if it returns anything?

Comment: @venkat I tried it myself and afte installing `ngCordova` and the contacts plugin it didn't work straight away. You need to include something in the `find()` function of the contacts plugin. I edited my answer to a working one.

Comment: yes i tried but it doesn't returns anything.. below is the code wrriten see once thanks in advance...

Comment: Does it give any errors in logs? Have you tried first without any service but to put it straight in you controller as it is? Do you have ngCordova installed correctly? Did you reset the plugins after installing them ie. removing and then adding the platform back?

Comment: .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
});

Comment: Can you edit your question and **ADD** the new code you have? The app.js and how have you included your ng-cordova files in your index.html?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a JSFiddle which contains my code.

Comment: Yep, sure thing. I added some points in my latest edit. Hopefully this will help you get it working.

Comment: what will be there in app.html?

Comment: In my simple demo just `<ion-view><ion-content><button type="button" ng-click="getAllContacts()" class="button button-block button-positive">Get contacts</button></ion-content></ion-view>`

Comment: hii i tried with above code but contcts are not reading on my application

Comment: i put your code in my files with the help of android studio and with my own device but it doesn't work plz solve it...

Comment: Paste your code in JSFiddle and link it to me. I will take a look.

Comment: how to link it to you in jsfiddle?

Comment: check my code linked in jsfiddle ..https://jsfiddle.net/venkaty/gjzhnyy5/

Comment: 1.created ionic project in the cmd prompt by command ionic start appname blank   2.after then cd appname 3.cordova plugin is added with command -cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts 4.added platform by command-ionic platform add android after then i have written code in app.js and index.html files 5. i imported the project in android studio and executed with the help of my mobile phone.6.the output is just an application is installed in my phone and when opened it consists of one button .7.when clicked it ..it is not importing device contacts

Comment: cordova installed version 6.3.0

Comment: ionic versio 1.7.16

Comment: @venkat Did you install `ngCordova` with the command `bower install ngCordova`? And have you looked at the logs if it gives you anything?

Comment: yes, ngcordova installed with that command only..Any wrong in my code and series of steps i have taken?@thepio

Comment: @venkat I can't spot anything wrong with what you have done. But I think you need to look at the logs to see if they tell you anything.

Comment: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=testApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20ngCordova%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'ngCordova'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.
the above is showing in android monitor..@thepio

Comment: had you run the code and check whether it is getting output or not ?

Comment: I ran my own code yes and it worked. Your error is clearly stating that `ngCordova` could not be found. See if it's installed correctly and look up the folder where it's installed in. Then make sure your path is correct in the index.html where you include the `ngCordova` script.

Comment: ngCordova is different from cordova?

Comment: if you dont mind can u plz tell me series of steps to be taken in order to execute and get all my contacts in to application?

Comment: 1. Have an Ionic application 2. Install ngCordova 3. Include ngCordova file BEFORE cordova.js but after ionic.js 4. Install ngCordova contacts plugin 5. Use `cordova platform remove <platform>` to remove platform and `cordova platform add <platform>` right after that to make sure plugins are installed 6. Just to make sure run `ionic state restore` 7. Insert the code that I've provided you with (**NOTE:** My code only console logs the contacts, it doesn't show them in app - use ng-repeat or something for this 8. Run the application in your phone

Comment: and also when installing any plugins etc to your application use the `--save` flag in the terminal. **Example:** `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts --save`. This way the plugin will be actually saved in your project and always installed when you do stuff. Also make sure your paths are correct for the files you include anywhere.

Comment: for every project i need to install ngCordova? @thepio

Comment: For the project that you are using!?!?!

Comment: in command prompt by using cmd:    bower install ngCordova is that right? @thepio

Comment: in 3rd step u said to include ngCordova file in index.html. is that right what i am thinking?@thepio

Comment: Yes, look at the example fiddle I provided you with in the answer.

Comment: Well all I can say is that look at the logs or something. Hire a person who can do it for you or something. I really don't think I can help you anymore.

Comment: 09-22 15:29:01.277 884-1918/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 24537:com.freecharge.android/u0a260 (adj 15): empty #6
09-22 15:29:10.375 345-345/? I/Gobi: vendor/qcom/proprietary/RIDL/RIDLClient/RIDLSQL.cpp:1920: GetTransState() EBADF
09-22 15:29:10.375 345-345/? I/Gobi: vendor/qcom/proprietary/RIDL/RIDLClient/MainCore.cpp:1346: Failed to get TransState, rc 
 this is displayed in logs when executing the programe to get all contacts @thepio

Comment: another question ; in a group the admin of group created an event and that notification is send to all group members asking for acceptance and if they accepted the event then on particular date and time there should be a notifications to all members to remembered them that they have a meeting ...i get all ok but the last specification i specified regarding firing on time notification is not working?.help me

Comment: @venkat you need to ask a new separate question for these things. Stop commenting on this post.